# Should we have an accept rate here?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer

Over on Programmers, accept rate doesn't show up on your card when you ask a question.  I wonder if we shouldn't adopt the same model here, since a lot of questions are going to bring very different answers from different viewpoints and make it hard to pick a single objective "right answer" the way we can on the more technical SE sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is incorrect. See [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/28098/why-does-it-matter-that-html-and-css-are-not-programming-languages), for example.

Accept rates are shown on *all* Stack Exchange sites, except per-site metas (such as this one). They are sometimes not shown, however, when the user has asked very few questions. [See this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34715/accept-rate-percentage/34716#34716) for the exact rules for when the accept rate is shown on a main site.

Also, [Jeff has hinted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64279/add-a-configuration-option-to-remove-the-accept-rate-from-the-user-box/104814#104814) that the accept rate might be replaced with some other statistic in the near future.

Comment: Ah.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: And here's a blog post on the subject **[New Question-Asker Features](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/)**

Comment: Accept rates are **not** shown on all Stack Exchange sites. Take a look at StackApps.com

Answer (score 4):

There is a fundamental misunderstanding here that "there is no correct answer". In fact there is usually a correct answer to questions about Christianity - and the answer is often "this group believes this, while that group believes that". A good answer describes them all, and when you get such an answer you should accept it. Unfortunately they are all too rare at the moment.